# Why is my for only working on the first variable?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, input, 2d

The code i wrote works fine if i type in COSC 1337
but once i type any of the other elements in the array it will display my error message instead of the time and date

what am i doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Schedule {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] arr = new String[4][2];
        arr[0][0] = "COSC 1337";
        arr[1][0] = "HIST 1301";
        arr[2][0] = "MATH 1302";
        arr[3][0] = "PHIL 1320";
        arr[0][1] = "Wednesdays 12pm-3pm";
        arr[1][1] = "Fridays 8am-11am";
        arr[2][1] = "Mondays 6pm-9pm";
        arr[3][1] = "Saturdays 10am-1pm";

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Course");
        String userInput = in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i][0])) {
                System.out.println("classes are on: " + arr[i][1]);
                return;
            }
            if (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i][0])) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Course");
                return;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I added the java tag. Some people only search for questions on their favourite language, so questions without a language tag don't get as many views.

Comment: wow thanks dude, that was thoughtful of you

Comment: Note also that this pattern, called "parallel arrays", is nearly always a sign of a design problem. In this case, you should instead have a `class Course` that contains the course number and the schedule, and then have an array of courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never do anything more than the first iteration in the loop.  The Invalid Course statement should be outside the for-loop and will only be called if all 4 course checks fail

Answer (score 0):

Your code says:

```
if strings match
    print message
    return

if strings don't match
    print message
    return
```

So you always return after looking at the first element. One way to get what you need is:

```
for each string
    if (string matches)
        print "classes on" message
        return
// If we get here we didn't match any string (because we didn't return)
print "didn't match any strings" error message
```

Comment: so what should i do instead

Comment: Have a flag that is false by default. If in any iteration the entered value matches the current string the flag should be toggled to true. Only if _after_ the loop the flag is still false, _then_ you can print your error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking both match and mismatch each time through the loop. You do not need to check for a mismatch. If it gets to the end of the loop without finding a match, it must be invalid.  Try this code change:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 4 ; i++)
{
    if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase( arr[i][0]))
    {
        System.out.println("classes are on: " + arr[i][1]);
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println("Invalid Course");
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning back in the else condition so what you are actually doing is skipping execution and returning from the function . I have corrected your code for you in the same format

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Schedule {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                String [][]arr = new String[4][2];
                arr[0][0] = "COSC 1337";
                arr[1][0] = "HIST 1301";
                arr[2][0] = "MATH 1302";
                arr[3][0] = "PHIL 1320";
                arr[0][1] = "Wednesdays 12pm-3pm";
                arr[1][1] = "Fridays 8am-11am";
                arr[2][1] = "Mondays 6pm-9pm";
                arr[3][1] = "Saturdays 10am-1pm";

                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter a Course");
                String userInput = in.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i< 4 ; i++)
                {
                    if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase( arr[i][0]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("classes are on: " + arr[i][1]);
                        return;
                    }

                }
                 System.out.println("Invalid Course");

            }


}
```